# JS how to get date&time in specific format

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm trying to get a log to read the current date in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm`

Here is my current code:

```
var dateformat = require("dateformat");
var now = new Date();
var s = dateformat(now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm");
console.log(s.toString());
```

The output i get is:

```
YYYY-06-DD 10:08
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read the documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat).

It should be `yyyy` for years, and `dd` for days, not uppercase.

```
var s = dateformat(now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
```

Update: The others you use are also wrong, they mean something else than what you intend. See Cohars' answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat):

```
// Basic usage 
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
// Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
```

And be careful with upper/lowercase. (In you code the only working things are `MM` for minutes and `mm` for month.)

So I guess you want something like:

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM
```

(Take a look at the [readme](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat) to see the differences between `h`,`hh`, `HH` etc).